# Parsing input using the python2.7 argsparse with other Language support

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("name", help="Enter the name")

args = parser.parse_args()
name = args.name

print name
```

Command:

```
python work_space.py அரவிந்த்
```

Output:

```
????????
```

Command

```
python work_space.py åäö
```

Output:

```
σΣ÷
```

I am not able to get the text which I need, Also I am in need to concatenate this input text, Please let me know what module I have to use and How to implement it?

Comment: Any specific reason you're still using Python 2? It's not supported anymore, and Unicode handling got much easier with Python 3.

Comment: If you able to solve in python3, please let me know

Comment: For solving this in Python 3, run the script through the `2to3` exectuable (which for this example only adds parentheses to `print`). You might have to export `PYTHONIOENCODING="utf8"` or fiddle with the locale to get input/output encoding to work properly.

Comment: I also ran this with Python 2, which seemed to work on first sight, but when I added `print name.upper()`, the argument `åäö` didn't get uppercased. You can also test this with `print name == u'åäö'`. This means that a symmetric misencoding is happening, and more work is required on getting the encoding right.